# Angular CDK drag and drop wrong drag direction when container rotates

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm implementing drag and drop on a checkers like game, all working fine ... until the board is rotated then all dnd and implementation is broken: when I drag a piece to the top, the piece goes to bottom, when is dragged to the left, goes to the right.

Sample code of the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3xixz?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

this is the fragment of css who breaks the dnd behavior, but I really need to rotate the board dinamically during the game.

```
.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

I don want to discard the @angular/cdk implementation, but maybe I have no choice, I am going nuts.

*UPDATE*

For more clarity of the issue I'm attaching an example with an animation to rotate the container. I'm already have a workaround for this, which I will share in the answers.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3xixz-2t148v

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using transform in CSS, use in HTML like this-

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
  <div style="transform:rotate(180deg)">
      Drag me around
  </div>
</div>
```

In your CSS-

```
.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
  
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks, but I am aplying the transform in the container of cdkDrag element not only the cdkDrag element, because that is what I need to rotate: the board, not the piece. 

```
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container"  style="transform:rotate(180deg)">
   <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
 Drag me around
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround for this, overriding the property *style.transform* of the native HTML element which is manipulated with Angular CDK Library, basically I changed the sign of the translation for reverting it, multiplying for -1.

My workaround looks something like this:

```
dragMoved(ev: CdkDragMove) {
  if (this.isRotated) {
    const [origX, origY] = this.elementRef.nativeElement.firstChild.style.transform.match(/-*\d+px/g);
    const newX = parseInt(origX, 10) * -1;
    const newY = parseInt(origY, 10) * -1;

    this.elementRef.nativeElement.firstChild.style.transform = `translate3d(${newX}px, ${newY}px, 0px)`;
  }
}
```